# Solution verification: Some preimage and image proofs of a map

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $f : A \to B$ and let $A_0 \subset A$ and
$B_0 \subset B$.

(a) We will show that $A_0 \subset f^{-1}[f[A_0]]$, with equality
if $f$ is injective.

Proof: let $x \in A_0$, then $f(x) \in f[A_0]$.  This,
by definition of the preimage of $f[A_0]$ under $f$, implies that
$x \in f^{-1}[f[A_0]]$, and therefore
$A_0 \subset f^{-1}[f[A_0]]$.  Assume $f$ is injective, and
let $x \in f^{-1}[f[A_0]]$, which implies $f(x) \in f[A_0]$
for exactly one $x \in f^{-1}[f[A_0]]$.  In other words, there
are no $a \in A_0$ with $a \neq x$ such that $f(a) = f(x) \in f[A_0]$.
Thus, $x \in A_0 \Rightarrow f^{-1}[f[A_0]] \subset A_0$,
and we are done.

(b) We will show that $f[f^{-1}[B_0]] \subset B_0$, with equality
if $f$ is surjective.

Proof: let $y \in f[f^{-1}[B_0]]$, then $y = f(a)$ for some
$a \in f^{-1}[B_0]$, which implies that $f(a) \in B_0$ by
definition of $f^{-1}[B_0]$.  Therefore, $y \in B_0$ and we can
conclude that $f[f^{-1}[B_0]] \subset B_0$.  Assume $f$ is
surjective, and let $y \in B_0$.  Let $y \in B_0$. By surjectivity, then there is some $a \in f^{-1}[B_0]$ such that $f(a) = y$. Therefore, $y \in f[f^{-1}[B_0]]$ which implies the desired result.

Comment: "In other words, there are no $a \in A_0$ with $a \neq x$ such that $f(a) \in f[A_0]$." This is not correct. What you probably meant was there there's no $a \in A_0$ with $a \neq x$ such that $f(a) =f(x)$. There's a slightly less confusing way of putting this; since $f(x) \in f[A_0]$, we know that there exists an $a \in A_0$ with $f(a)= f(x)$ but this implies, by injectivity, that $a=x$.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern Hi, I agree with what you said, including that your suggestion is less confusing, however why is it wrong?

Comment: Well, when you say "there are no $a \in A_0$ with $a \neq x$ such that $f(a) \in f[A_0]$", this sort of indicates $A_0 = \{x\}$ or $A_0 = \varnothing$. After all, if $A_0$ was anything else, then you would have a $y \in A_0$ with $y \neq x$ and $f(y) \in f[A_0]$. But this isn't what you're going for

Comment: I understand what you mean, yes that's definitely not the intended interpretation. I will edit my post.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern What about the rest of the proof?

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your surjectivity argument. So, you let $y \in B_0$. I get that. Then, you say that there is at least one $a \in f^{-1}[B_0]$ such that $f(a) \in B_0$ and $f(a) = y$. You seem to repeat this statement twice, for some reason. It's kind of weird, though the idea seems fine.

Comment: Here's a better way to phrase this: Let $y \in B_0$. Since $f$ is surjective, there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = y$. Since $f(a) \in B_0$, it follows that $a \in f^{-1}[B_0]$. But this implies that $f(a) \in f(f^{-1}[B_0])$. This means that $y \in f(f^{-1}[B_0])$.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern Basically, I wanted to first state why there exists such an element in those sets, and then I apply surjectivity to get that it 'reaches' $y$.

Comment: Ah okay. So, the thing is, that's actually incorrect. See, you need surjectivity to guarantee that $a$ actually exists in the first place. The definition of $f^{-1}[B_0]$ actually, then, forces $a \in f^{-1}[B_0]$. You need the thing that you're looking for to actually exist first before you can talk about it being in some set or not.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern I don't need it, because we're not talking about $y$ just yet; we don't need surjectivity because we implicitly assume the sets are nonempty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138337/discussion-between-mordeus-morgenstern-and-polite-proofs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so I've writtne most of my feedback about your proof in the comments above. This is going to focus on how I would phrase my own arguments. I'm going to actually prove the parts where it says "with equality if $f$ is...."

1. $A_0 =f^{-1}[f[A_0]]$.

We know that $A_0 \subseteq f^{-1}[f[A_0]]$. Let $x \in f^{-1}[f[A_0]]$. Then, $f(x) \in f[A_0]$. Since $f(x) \in f[A_0]$, there exists an $a \in A_0$ such that $f(a) = f(x)$. Since $f$ is  injective, it follows that $a = x$. But this implies that $x \in A_0$ and we are done.

2. $B_0=f[f^{-1}[B_0]]$.

We know that $f[f^{-1}[B_0]] \subseteq B_0$. Let $y \in B_0$. Since $f$ is surjective, there is an $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$. Then, $x \in f^{-1}[B_0]$. But this implies that $f(x) \in f[f^{-1}[B_0]]$ and this means that $y \in f[f^{-1}[B_0]]$. So, we are done.